# Best Way to Reset Browser State in TestNG with Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Can someone recommend the best way to 'tearDown' in the @AfterClass with testng? I occasionally get a hung window or popup and can't get back to the homepage to logout gracefully for the next class to start and avoid modal dialog errors.

I've tried getting a window handle on the homepage, then one on the popup, then putting a switchTo in my @AfterClass but it doesn't work. I've also tried driver.close(). But then my next class will be skipped with an unreachable browser error.

I really need a good tearDown @AfterClass method that can get out of whatever errors and popups are on page, and just leave a clean browser window at login page for the next test class to run.

Edit: Adding Code:

```
package TestPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;    

//@Test (priority = 1)
public class test1 {
    public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    Environment environment = Environment.QA03();
    User testUser = User.ns_system();
    AxUtilities axUtilities;

    @BeforeClass
    @Parameters("environment")
    @Test
    public void login(String environment1){

//        environment = new Environment(environment1);
        axUtilities  = new DAxUtilities(environment1, driver);
//        DAxUtilities dAxUtilities = new DAxUtilities(environment);
        Login login = new Login();
        login.getLogin(testUser, axUtilities, driver);
        axUtilities.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test
    public void testNothing(){
        String s = "public void testNothing() reached...";
        System.out.println(s);
    }


    @AfterClass
    public void verifyOKAndLogout() {

        driver.quit();
//        DAxUtilities dAxUtilities;

    }

}
```

test class 1 and 2 are the same except for the class name...

And the tests are run from xml file. And I've tried many variants of the xml file, even putting each test in its own xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="TestSuite1" verbose="1">
    <parameter name="environment" value="QA03"/>

<test name="Test1">
    <classes>
        <class name="TestPackage.test1"/>
        <!--<class name="TestPackage.test2"/>-->
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Test2">
    <classes>
        <class name="TestPackage.test2"/>
    </classes>
</test>

</suite>
```

But always two web drivers get created, one right after the other, at the very beginning of the test run, before any other code is executed. And breakpoints show the code is definitely skipping from the beginning of class 1, to the beginning of class 2, before running class 1 tests...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you wrote it seems that you are creating browser (instantiating WebDriver) before entire test suite and then execute all the tests using the same browser instance. Although it results with faster execution time it also introduces problems like the one you are having right now.

I would suggest creating a new instance of the browser before executing each test class (or even test method). In such case you can safely use `driver.quit()` in your @AfterClass method. Restarting browser every test will make your tests much more stable.

**EDIT** comments on your newly added code

- the way you are instantiating WebDriver is not correct. If you have
  several test classes you will end up with multiple browser windows
  opened before any test is executed
- you annotated one method with both @Test and @BeforeClass - this will cause the method to be executed twice in a row

The way it should (more or less) looks like is

```
public class MyTest {
   protected WebDriver driver;

   @BeforeClass   //I would even suggest to use @BeforeMethod but that's up to you
   public void setUp() {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      //other instantiations and assignments if necessary
   }

   @Test
   public void login() {
      driver.get("http://watever.com");
      //do whatever
   }

   @Test
   public void someOtherTest() {
      //do something else
   }

   @AfterClass   //or @AfterMethod
   public void tearDown() {
      driver.quit();
   }
}
```

Comment: I whole heartedly agree that sharing browsers between tests will lead to unreliable, unstable and unusable tests

Comment: Actually I am *trying* to run my tests exactly as you describe but it is not working. TestNG is skipping around from one class to another and destroying my driver initializations. Please see my other post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516227/testng-is-running-classes-out-of-order-skipping-between-classes-of-tests

Comment: I should clarify, when I run driver.quit() in one class, in the @AfterClass, then my next class won't run. Even though a new webdriver is initialized at the very top. It will be skipped. It will throw and unreachable browser error. Testng initializes the webdriver for class1, then immediately skips to class2 and initializes the webdriver for class2 (yes, really!), then skips back to class 1 and starts running tests. I can't do a driver.close() at the end of class1 because class2's driver initialization has already run- too soon, and won't run again when actually needed. I hope this is clear...

Comment: @JackRyan Please post your code either here or in the topic you linked. That will make easier for us to pinpoint source of the problem.

Comment: OK, test code added. This isn't my actual test of course. I started completely from scratch this weekend and still getting the same issue. Seriously hope you can help as I am totally stuck on this one.

Comment: @JackRyan I've edited my post and added additional comments and sample code. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: All of the answers were accurate but this one most closely solved my problem. To be clear, there is more to the answer than just what is posted. Actually all classes and variables being used by the test class should be declared at the class level (to be in scope for the whole class) and be instantiated within a method (setup in this example). Even say 'int i = 32;' outside of a method, at the class level will cause @BeforeClass to be run twice. And even worse, it can cause testng to initialize all the variables in class1, then move to class2 and do the same, then back to class1 to run tests!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that calling `driver.close()` or `driver.quit()` and then creating a new WebDriver and assigning it to your driver should do the trick.  You'd probably want to call the same function to create the driver at both the beginning and end of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@tearDown{
driver.quit();

}
```

It will close all the windows open by test class.

And in the Next class create new instance of Webdriver() as shown below

`Webdriver driver = new FireFoxDriver();`  //Or some  other driver